# Cleanly determine actions given an enum tuple

Tags: c#

I am trying to determine the cleanest (it's good enough if it can be understood easily) way to determine which actions to execute given a list of tuples.
Let's say I have the table MyType and the table MyAction. These tables are joined by a middle table ActionsPerType, since MyType has a many-to-many relationship to MyAction.

Now, the idea is to execute the actions ActionsPerType declares, for example:

```
Dictionary<int, int> actionsPerType = context.ActionsPerType
    .GroupBy(c => c.MyTypeId)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Key.MyTypeId, c.ToList());
```

I want to convert this to a `Dictionary<int, Func<Task<decimal>>>` where the `Key` is the `actionsPerType.Key` and the `Value` is a list of `async Task<decimal>` defined in the code.

Is there any cleaner approach to this than something like (done here, untested):

```
foreach (var item in actionsPerType)
{
    switch ((MyTypeEnum)item.Key)
    {
        case MyTypeEnum.Random:
        {
            foreach (var action in actionsPerType[MyTypeEnum.Random])
            {
                switch ((MyActionEnum)action)
                {
                    case MyActionEnum.Random:
                        dictionary[MyTypeEnum.Random].Add(SomeTaskThatReturnsBool);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyTypeEnum would hold around 10 items while MyActionEnum would hold near 25, so this would be really long and ugly.

Comment: Try this : Dictionary<int, List<int>> actionsPerType = context.ActionsPerType
    .GroupBy(c => c.MyTypeId, d => d)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, d.ToList()); You can call a helper method with 'd' as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm a big fan of Attributes. I'm not entirely sure of the desired outcome and if the following suits your situation, but here goes.

Because `enum`s are considered constants, they can be used inside attribute parameters. Therefore the following is possible:

```
public enum TypeEnum{
    T1,T2
}

public enum ActionEnum{
    A1,A2
}

public static class SomeClass
{
    [TypeAction(TypeEnum.T1, ActionEnum.A1)]
    public static void Foo(){
    }

    [TypeAction(TypeEnum.T1, ActionEnum.A2)]
    [TypeAction(TypeEnum.T2, ActionEnum.A2)] //<-- example of method can be used for multiple types/actions
    public static void Bar(){
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)] // <- AllowMultiple in case an action can be used multiple times
public class TypeActionAttribute:Attribute
{   
    public TypeActionAttribute(TypeEnum type, ActionEnum action)
    {
        this.Type=type;
        this.Action = action;           
    }

    public TypeEnum Type{get;set;}
    public ActionEnum Action{get;set;}
}
```

Once the attribute-class is created, each enum combi can be assigned to any method. Obtaining all methods can be done in runtime (preferable once during initialization and memoized).
Probably a list of possible combinations is most useful in the long run, but your example seems to need only the `TypeEnum` with all methods (ActionEnum is not stored in the pseudecode), which would be equivalent in something like:

```
var typeMethods = (from m in typeof(SomeClass).GetMethods() //the methods are probably based in multiple types. Depending where they can be found, the types of an Assembly can be queried
            from a in m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TypeActionAttribute), true)              
            group m by ((TypeActionAttribute)a).Type)
            .ToDictionary(gr=>gr.Key, gr=>gr.ToList());
```

`typemethods` will be a dictionary of TypeEnum with lists of methodinfo's. (The methodinfos can be invoked or processed to specific lambdas)

Comment: I accepted your answer because I like it, but we decided to do this by using an intermediate table

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer given by @Me.Name.  However if for some weird reason Attributes are not a choice why not use a dictionary of tasks:

```
Dictionary<MyActionEnum, Func<Task<decimal>>> tasks = new Dictionary<MyActionEnum, Func<Task<decimal>>> {
                { MyActionEnum.A1, __Task1 },
                { MyActionEnum.A2, __Task2 },
                { MyActionEnum.A3, __Task3 },
                { MyActionEnum.A4, __Task4 },
                { MyActionEnum.A5, async () => { return await Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(result =>  new Decimal(16)); } }
            };
static async Task<decimal> __Task1() { return await Task.FromResult<decimal>(new Decimal(420)); }
// etc
```

IF I understand your requirements then this should fit neatly with linq, and I suppose an advantage here is that the dictionary allows for runtime dynamics.